# Fast loan rate calculation for a big number of loans

Tags: r, finance

I have a big data set (around 200k rows) where each row is a loan. I have the loan amount, the number of payments, and the loan payment.
I'm trying to get the loan rate.
R doesn't have a function for calculating this (at least base R doesn't have it, and I couldn't find it).
It isn't that hard to write both a npv and irr functions

```
Npv <- function(i, cf, t=seq(from=0,by=1,along.with=cf)) sum(cf/(1+i)^t)
Irr <- function(cf) { uniroot(npv, c(0,100000), cf=cf)$root }
```

And you can just do

```
rate = Irr(c(amt,rep(pmt,times=n)))
```

The problem is when you try to calculate the rate for a lot of payments. Because uniroot is not vectorized, and because rep takes a surprising amount of time, you end up with a slow calculation. You can make it faster if you do some math and figure out that you are looking for the roots of the following equation

```
zerome <- function(r) amt/pmt-(1-1/(1+r)^n)/r
```

and then use that as input for uniroot. This, in my pc, takes around 20 seconds to run for my 200k database.

The problem is that I'm trying to do some optimization, and this is a step of the optimization, so I'm trying to speed it up even more.

I've tried vectorization, but because uniroot is not vectorized, I can't go further that way. Is there any root finding method that is vectorized?

Thanks

Comment: First, I'd put the call to rep outside the call to Irr, since it seems to be the same each time. Second, if I recall correctly, it should be possible with a little effort to convert your calculation to a call to polyroot instead of uniroot (not that I guarantee that's faster, but I'd guess it might be). Third, it's easy to vectorize functions, not least by Vectorize. Fourth, good starting points can help.  Any of those might speed things up.

Comment: @Glen_b 
1-the problem is not that rep runs each time uniroot iterates, but that it runs each time a loan is calculated, and that's right each one has a different amount of payments
2-polyroot returns all roots, not just the first (in this case, there's only one root, but if there are more it may be slower)
3- I tried Vectorize, but uniroot is not vectorizable, that has been discussed a lot
4- uniroot uses an starting interval, not point. I agree with that, but in this case there were some strange loans with wild rates, and cause of that I couldn't put a narrow interval there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using a root finder, you could use a linear interpolator. You will have to create one interpolator for each value of `n` (the number of remaining payments). Each interpolator will map `(1-1/(1+r)^n)/r` to `r`. Of course you will have to build a grid fine enough so it will return `r` to an acceptable precision level. The nice thing with this approach is that linear interpolators are fast and vectorized: you can find the rates for all loans with the same number of remaining payments (`n`) in a single call to the corresponding interpolator.

Now some code that proves it is a viable solution:

First, we create interpolators, one for each possible value of `n`:

```
n.max <- 360L  # 30 years

one.interpolator <- function(n) {
    r <- seq(from = 0.0001, to = 0.1500, by = 0.0001)
    y <- (1-1/(1+r)^n)/r
    approxfun(y, r)
}

interpolators <- lapply(seq_len(n.max), one.interpolator)
```

Note that I used a precision of 1/100 of a percent (1bp).

Then we create some fake data:

```
n.loans <- 200000L
n     <- sample(n.max, n.loans, replace = TRUE)
amt   <- 1000 * sample(100:500, n.loans, replace = TRUE)
pmt   <- amt / (n * (1 - runif(n.loans)))
loans <- data.frame(n, amt, pmt)
```

Finally, we solve for `r`:

```
library(plyr)
system.time(ddply(loans, "n", transform, r = interpolators[[n[1]]](amt / pmt)))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   2.684   0.423   3.084
```

It's fast. Note that some of the output rates are `NA` but it is because my random inputs made no sense and would have returned rates outside of the [0 ~ 15%] grid I selected. Your real data won't have that problem.

Comment: Nice!! I agree that 1bps is enough (I use that). This is even faster than a vectorized root finder probably. As for the real data, regretably it has some outliers and therefore I'll need a bigger grid, but I don't think that that will be a problem for the timing of the operation