# Improve performance of the np.irr function through vectorization

Tags: python, numpy

Is it possible to improve the performance of the np.irr function such that it can applied to a 2-dimension array of cash flows without using a for-loop--either though vectorizing the np.irr function or through an alternative algorithm?

The irr function in the numpy library calculates the periodically compounded rate of return that gives a net present value of 0 for an array of cash flows. This function can only be applied to a 1-dimensional array:

```
x = np.array([-100,50,50,50])
r = np.irr(x)
```

np.irr will not work against a 2-dimensional array of cash flows, such as:

```
cfs = np.zeros((10000,4))
cfs[:,0] = -100
cfs[:,1:] = 50
```

where each row represents a series of cash flows, and columns represent time periods. Therefore a slow implementation would be to loop over each row and apply np.irr to individual rows:

```
out = []
for x in cfs:
    out.append(np.irr(x))
```

For large arrays, this is an optimization barrier. Looking at the source code of the np.irr function, I believe the main obstacle is vectorizing the np.roots function:

```
def irr(values):
    res = np.roots(values[::-1])
    mask = (res.imag == 0) & (res.real > 0)
    if res.size == 0:
        return np.nan
    res = res[mask].real
    # NPV(rate) = 0 can have more than one solution so we return
    # only the solution closest to zero.
    rate = 1.0/res - 1
    rate = rate.item(np.argmin(np.abs(rate)))
    return rate
```

I have found a similar implementation in R: [Fast loan rate calculation for a big number of loans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868990/fast-loan-rate-calculation-for-a-big-number-of-loans), but don't know how to port this into Python. Also, I don't consider np.apply_along_axis or np.vectorize to be solutions to this issue since my main concern is performance, and I understand both are wrappers for a for-loop.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the question you linked is about the special case of loans with a fixed payback amount, while `np.irr` handles arbitrary cash flows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the source of `np.roots`,

```
import inspect
print(inspect.getsource(np.roots))
```

We see that it works by finding the eigenvalues of the "companion matrix". It also does some special handling of coefficients that are zero. I really don't understand the mathematical background, but I do know that `np.linalg.eigvals` can calculate eigenvalues for multiple matrices in a vectorized way.

Merging it with the source of `np.irr` has resulted in the following "Frankencode":

```
def irr_vec(cfs):
    # Create companion matrix for every row in `cfs`
    M, N = cfs.shape
    A = np.zeros((M, (N-1)**2))
    A[:,N-1::N] = 1
    A = A.reshape((M,N-1,N-1))
    A[:,0,:] = cfs[:,-2::-1] / -cfs[:,-1:]  # slice [-1:] to keep dims

    # Calculate roots; `eigvals` is a gufunc
    res = np.linalg.eigvals(A)

    # Find the solution that makes the most sense...
    mask = (res.imag == 0) & (res.real > 0)
    res = np.ma.array(res.real, mask=~mask, fill_value=np.nan)
    rate = 1.0/res - 1
    idx = np.argmin(np.abs(rate), axis=1)
    irr = rate[np.arange(M), idx].filled()
    return irr
```

This does not do handling of zero coefficients and surely fails when `any(cfs[:,-1] == 0)`. Also some input argument checking wouldn't hurt. And some other problems maybe? But for the supplied example data it achieves what we wanted (at the cost of increased memory use):

```
In [487]: cfs = np.zeros((10000,4))
     ...: cfs[:,0] = -100
     ...: cfs[:,1:] = 50

In [488]: %timeit [np.irr(x) for x in cfs]
1 loops, best of 3: 2.96 s per loop

In [489]: %timeit irr_vec(cfs)
10 loops, best of 3: 77.8 ms per loop
```

If you have the special case of loans with a fixed payback amount (like in the question you linked) you may be able do it faster using interpolation...

Comment: Hi @moarningsun. Thanks for your contribution. I'm actually unable to replicate your results, getting an error. Is this a numpy version error?

```>>> irr_vec(cfs)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in irr_vec
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 767, in eigvals
    _assertRank2(a)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 155, in _assertRank2
    'two-dimensional' % len(a.shape))
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: 3-dimensional array given. Array must be two-dimensional```

Comment: @BenSigrin, could be; the minimum Numpy version is 1.8.0

Answer (score 4):

After I posted this question I worked on this question and came up with a vectorized solution that uses a different algorithm:

```
def virr(cfs, precision = 0.005, rmin = 0, rmax1 = 0.3, rmax2 = 0.5):
    ''' 
    Vectorized IRR calculator. First calculate a 3D array of the discounted
    cash flows along cash flow series, time period, and discount rate. Sum over time to 
    collapse to a 2D array which gives the NPV along a range of discount rates 
    for each cash flow series. Next, find crossover where NPV is zero--corresponds
    to the lowest real IRR value. For performance, negative IRRs are not calculated
    -- returns "-1", and values are only calculated to an acceptable precision.

    IN:
        cfs - numpy 2d array - rows are cash flow series, cols are time periods
        precision - level of accuracy for the inner IRR band eg 0.005%
        rmin - lower bound of the inner IRR band eg 0%
        rmax1 - upper bound of the inner IRR band eg 30%
        rmax2 - upper bound of the outer IRR band. eg 50% Values in the outer 
                band are calculated to 1% precision, IRRs outside the upper band 
                return the rmax2 value
    OUT:
        r - numpy column array of IRRs for cash flow series
    '''

    if cfs.ndim == 1: 
        cfs = cfs.reshape(1,len(cfs))

    # Range of time periods
    years = np.arange(0,cfs.shape[1])

    # Range of the discount rates
    rates_length1 = int((rmax1 - rmin)/precision) + 1
    rates_length2 = int((rmax2 - rmax1)/0.01)
    rates = np.zeros((rates_length1 + rates_length2,))
    rates[:rates_length1] = np.linspace(0,0.3,rates_length1)
    rates[rates_length1:] = np.linspace(0.31,0.5,rates_length2)

    # Discount rate multiplier rows are years, cols are rates
    drm = (1+rates)**-years[:,np.newaxis]

    # Calculate discounted cfs   
    discounted_cfs = cfs[:,:,np.newaxis] * drm

    # Calculate NPV array by summing over discounted cashflows
    npv = discounted_cfs.sum(axis = 1)

    ## Find where the NPV changes sign, implies an IRR solution
    signs = npv < 0

    # Find the pairwise differences in boolean values when sign crosses over, the
    # pairwise diff will be True
    crossovers = np.diff(signs,1,1)

    # Extract the irr from the first crossover for each row
    irr = np.min(np.ma.masked_equal(rates[1:]* crossovers,0),1)

    # Error handling, negative irrs are returned as "-1", IRRs greater than rmax2 are
    # returned as rmax2
    negative_irrs = cfs.sum(1) < 0
    r = np.where(negative_irrs,-1,irr)
    r = np.where(irr.mask * (negative_irrs == False), 0.5, r)

    return r
```

Performance:

```
import numpy as np
cfs = np.zeros((10000,4))
cfs[:,0] = -100
cfs[:,1:] = 50

%timeit [np.irr(x) for x in cfs]
10 loops, best of 3: 1.06 s per loop

%timeit virr(cfs)
10 loops, best of 3: 29.5 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

pyxirr is super fast, and np.irr is deprecated, so I'd use this now:

https://pypi.org/project/pyxirr/

```
import pyxirr

cfs = np.zeros((10000,4))
cfs[:,0] = -100
cfs[:,1:] = 50

df = pd.DataFrame(cfs).T
df.apply(pyxirr.irr)
```

Comment: I also went this route, but in certain edge cases such as negative cashflow values we get some unexpected results or exceptions, where the slower numpy financial still returns the expected result.  Just something to be aware of.